# How to remove a field from all collections?

Tags: mongodb

Can you remove a field from all collections in mongodb? I explain myself, let's think i have 3 databases called db1, db2 and db3. And random documents in them with fields and data. Is there any command to remove certain field from all of that databases or you can just remove a field from all documents?

Comment: There is an $unset operator, you can apply it across all documents
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/

Comment: Yes, i know about that operator but my question goes about collections, not documents. I want to know if a field can be removed from all collections using a command.

Comment: I am afraid there is no one command to do that, you'll have to use loops to remove field across all databases and their collections

Comment: Thanks! I was just wondering beacuse i'm doing some mongodb now and my teacher asked me for that, but i think he didn't meant collections but documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you wanted to remove `field1` from all documents 
You'll have to loop through `db1`, `db2` and their respective collections, 
Then use `$unset` to remove the field

```
var dbList = ["db1", "db2"]
var mongo = new Mongo()
dbList.forEach(function(dbName){
    var db = mongo.getDB(dbName)
    print("Removing from db: "+dbName)
    db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collName){
        print("\tRemoving from collection: "+collName)
        db.getCollection(collName).updateMany({}, {$unset:{"field1":""}})
    })  

})
```